# How to define similar class-functions related to different class-properties inside __init__

Tags: python, class

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def f_1(self,x):
        return foo(x, self.property_1)

    def f_2(self,x):
        return foo(x, self.property_2)
```

The idea is that multiple functions `f_n` have a common structure, but depend on different properties `property_n` of the class.

I look for a more compact way to define those `f_n` in the `__init__`? I think of something like

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.f_1 = self.construct_function(self.property_1)
        self.f_2 = self.construct_function(self.property_2)

    def construct_function(self, property):
        # ???
```

That is what I have in mind, but I dont know how to define this `construct_function`. It  is important that 'property' is of a point-by-value type.

**Edit:**

I simplified [Martijn's very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15809599/1954677) to this solution, which works fine:

```
def construct_function(property_name):
    def f_n(self, x):
        return foo(x, getattr(self, property_name))

    return f_n

class MyClass2(object):

    f_1 = construct_function('property_1')
    f_2 = construct_function('property_2')
```

Just wanted to mention it here, as multiline comments are not allowed...

Comment: Are these functions constant for *all* instances or do they vary from instance to instance?

Comment: The functions are structurally the same for all instances, but of course depend on the individual instance `self`'s `self.propery_n`.

Comment: Sure, like all class methods, self is available to look up the attribute.

Comment: In other words, `construct_function` could also be defined outside the class.

Comment: Already done, see below. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate these methods *per class*, use a class decorator:

```
def property_functions(**properties):
    def construct_method(prop):
        def f_n(self):
            return foo(getattr(self, prop))
        return f_n

    def class_decorator(cls):
        for name, prop in properties.iteritems():
            setattr(cls, name, construct_method(prop))

        return cls

    return class_decorator
```

then use it like:

```
@property_functions(f_1='property_1', f_2='property_2')
class MyClass(object):
    property_1 = 'foo'
    property_2 = 'bar'
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> def foo(value): print value
... 
>>> @property_functions(f_1='property_1', f_2='property_2')
... class MyClass(object):
...     property_1 = 'foo'
...     property_2 = 'bar'
... 
>>> mc = MyClass()
>>> mc.f_1()
foo
>>> mc.f_2()
bar
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I think it can be done simpler for my case, even without decorators, but your basic idea (specifying the property's *name* as a string and then use `getattr`) really helps.

Comment: Finally reduced it to what I meant with *simpler and without decorators*, see edit in the original post. Thanks again!

Comment: @flonk: That is also fine. :-) My solution is a little more generic, it can be used for multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at **getattr**  or **getattribute** . They allow you dynamically create and reference attributes. For ex

It works something like this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return "You asked for %s, but I'm giving you default" % attribute


>>> bar = foo()
>>> bar.a
'a'
>>> bar.b
"You asked for b, but I'm giving you default"
>>> getattr(bar, "a")
'a'
>>> getattr(bar, "b")
"You asked for b, but I'm giving you default"
```